# Getting Fun White Square when Uploading to S3 via Put

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Friends, Countrymen, Lend me your ears...

I'm signing my url for amazon s3, and then using fileReader and Fetch to put my file in s3.
Though when I do I get a fun white square instead of my image:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/hubbble/Gabe/lX4H0.png

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = ((e) => {

  let s3headers = new Headers();
  s3headers.append("content-type", 'image/png');

  fetch(signedRequest, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: s3headers,
      body: e.currentTarget.result
  }).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

- Permissions Issue? Don't really think so as you can definitely view the image
- Corrupted somehow?
- Maybe an incorrect content type?

Thoughts?
Thanks for any guidance, been banging my head against the wall on this!

Comment: you should change the accepted answer which spells out explicitly what needs to happen a little more clearly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of that appear to be a base64 encoded image. That is, you're uploading a text file and not a binary image (and then saying it is, a `image/png`) You could just convert it first doing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) first.

Comment: You're a gentlemen and a scholar. I knew it had to be something like that. Ended up using fetch to read the file, as suggested in one of the answers. Super simple and worked great!

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is coming from a Node environment, the solution is to use the following code. I tested this and it works. There is no need for atob or doing some bytearray acrobatics.

```
      // base64DataString is the base64 string, which I assume you have
      // base64Data is a Buffer that is encoded in base64!
      // STEP 1: we remove the header of the dataUri string
      const base64Data = new Buffer.from(b64DataString.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');


      // STEP 2: CALL PUT OBJECT
      s3.putObject(
        {
          Bucket: "your bucket name",
          Key: `yourfile.jpg`, // the key for S3 location 
          Body: base64Data,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64', // important to tell that the incoming buffer is base64
          ContentType: "image/jpeg", // e.g. "image/jpeg" or "image/png"
          ACL:'public-read'
        },
        (err, data) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err)
            return;
          }
          console.log("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY:") //optional
          console.log(data) //optional
          resolve(data); // if this is in a promise, then include
        }
      )
```

Comment: This worked for me (specifically using a Buffer) thank you!

Comment: how to get that b64DataString. I have data attribute but its throwing error saying file.data.replace is not defined.